# PS command explanation why do some old process appear?

Tags: linux

From my understanding of linux ps command on linux it should display "current process".  I ran this command `ps aux --sort -rss`

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root     12019  0.0  2.5 224036 105992 ?       Ss   04:13   0:06 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/528/bin/perl -T -w /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/spamd --max-spare=
root     12237  0.0  2.4 225184 103664 ?       S    04:26   0:03 spamd child
root     12238  0.0  2.4 224036 102128 ?       S    04:26   0:00 spamd child
root     12239  0.0  2.4 224036 102124 ?       S    04:26   0:00 spamd child
mysql     1592  0.2  1.3 1586436 57104 ?       Sl   Aug29   1:56 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user
named     1056  0.0  0.9 1924092 41828 ?       Ssl  Aug29   0:00 /usr/sbin/named -u named
root      1380  0.0  0.8 902416 37480 ?        Ssl  Aug29   0:19 PM2 v3.5.1: God Daemon (/root/.pm2)         
root      5032  0.0  0.8 2037540 35732 ?       Sl   Aug29   0:01 phantomjs /home/ogdi/public_html/preview/productpreview/node-webshot/lib/webshot.phantom.js {
root      9778  0.0  0.8 2037500 35708 ?       Sl   02:57   0:01 phantomjs /home/ogdi/public_html/preview/productpreview/node-webshot/lib/webshot.phantom.js {
root     18725  0.0  0.8 2037500 35680 ?       Sl   08:09   0:00 phantomjs /home/ogdi/public_html/preview/productpreview/node-webshot/lib/webshot.phantom.js {
root      7577  0.0  0.8 2037460 35676 ?       Sl   01:46   0:01 phantomjs /home/ogdi/public_html/preview/productpreview/node-webshot/lib/webshot.phantom.js {
root      9740  0.0  0.8 2037500 35676 ?       Sl   02:54   0:01 phantomjs /home/ogdi/public_html/preview/productpreview/node-webshot/lib/webshot.phantom.js {
root     13955  0.0  0.8 2037500 35672 ?       Sl   05:23   0:00 phantomjs /home/ogdi/public_html/preview/productpreview/node-webshot/lib/webshot.phantom.js {
root      3342  0.0  0.8 2037460 35664 ?       Sl   Aug29   0:01 phantomjs /home/ogdi/public_html/preview/productpreview/node-webshot/lib/webshot.phantom.js {
root     18186  0.0  0.8 2037500 35664 ?       Sl   07:51   0:00 phantomjs /home/ogdi/public_html/preview/productpreview/node-
```

This is just part of it.  The Phantom process is on there a bunch of times bu tit says time is about 1 second and also hardly any memory.  Is that process still alive?

Comment: Can't tell what the processess are still doing, but they're there. And two of them are from yesterday (see the START column).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of those processes are "alive". They are active processes on your system.

You can determine the state of the process by looking at the `STAT` column, and checking the code listed against the table in the `ps` man page:

```
PROCESS STATE CODES
       Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output
       specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the state of
       a process:

               D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
               I    Idle kernel thread
               R    running or runnable (on run queue)
               S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
               T    stopped by job control signal
               t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
               W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
               X    dead (should never be seen)
               Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by
                    its parent

       For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional
       characters may be displayed:

               <    high-priority (not nice to other users)
               N    low-priority (nice to other users)
               L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
               s    is a session leader
               l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads
                    do)
               +    is in the foreground process group
```